# mongodb replication failed with socketexception and listener

Tags: replication, mongodb

I'm trying to set up mongodb replication using two servers in different data center. For the purposes of this question, I'll say their IP address are `1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2`.  I installed a clean version of centos8 and mongo with these commands on each server:

```
yum install -y yum-utils
cat <<EOT >> /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.4.repo
[mongodb-org-4.4]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/8Server/mongodb-org/4.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc
EOT
yum install -y mongodb-org-4.4.1 mongodb-org-server-4.4.1 mongodb-org-shell-4.4.1 mongodb-org-mongos-4.4.1 mongodb-org-tools-4.4.1
mkdir -p /data/db
sed -i "s/bindIp:.*/bindIp: 0.0.0.0/g" /etc/mongod.conf
systemctl start mongod
```

This worked great.  I can do `ssh root@1.1.1.1` and then I can run `mongo --host 2.2.2.2` to enter the mongo cli of server `2.2.2.2` from server `1.1.1.1`.  I can also `ssh root@2.2.2.2` and run `mongo --host 1.1.1.1` to enter the mongo cli of `server 1.1.1.1` from server `2.2.2.2`.

Next, I `ssh root@1.1.1.1`.  Then I ran the command:

```
 mongod --auth --replSet "rs0" --bind_ip localhost,2.2.2.2
```

But this failed and gave this output:

```
[root@li1953-23 ~]# mongod --auth --replSet "rs0" --bind_ip localhost,2.2.2.2
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.192+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.197+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.198+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.198+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.199+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":130556,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"li1953-23"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.199+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1c FIPS  28 May 2019","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"rhel80","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.199+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core) ","version":"Kernel 4.18.0-193.14.2.el8_2.x86_64"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.199+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"localhost,2.2.2.2"},"replication":{"replSet":"rs0"},"security":{"authorization":"enabled"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.200+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Cannot assign requested address"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.200+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784907, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the replica set node executor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-15T01:27:26.201+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
```

I am unable to continue with the mongodb tutorial on how to set up replication until I remedy this problem.  What did I do wrong and how do I fix?

---

**EXTRA - 2020-11-16 06:30**

I also tried to `ssh root@1.1.1.1` and then `mongo` to enter cli of mongo instance at `1.1.1.1`.  Then I ran this command:

```
rs.initiate( {
_id :  "rs0",
members: [
{ _id:  0, host:  "1.1.1.1:27017" },
{ _id:  1, host:  "2.2.2.2:27017" }
]
})
```

Which gives the error:

```
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "This node was not started with the replSet option",
        "code" : 76,
        "codeName" : "NoReplicationEnabled"
}
```

---

**EXTRA 2020-11-16 0900**

I made some slight progress by using `--bind-ip 0.0.0.0` and `--db-path /var/lib/mongo`.  What I did was

```
ssh root@1.1.1.1
systemctl stop mongod
rm -f /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock #this file doesn't seem to delete itself after shutdown
chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo* #for some reason, permissions are set to root after
mongod --auth --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --replSet "rs0" --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

My terminal window for `1.1.1.1` reports mongod is running, and I must leave this window open to keep things active.  I also make sure mongod is running on my `2.2.2.2` with the usual `systemctl start mongod`.

Now I open a new terminal window and do this:

```
ssh root@1.1.1.1
mongo #enter mongo cli
rs.initiate( {
_id :  "rs0",
members: [
{ _id:  0, host:  "1.1.1.1:27017" },
{ _id:  1, host:  "2.2.2.2:27017" }
]
})
```

But this results in the follow error:

```
rs.initiate( { _id :  "rs0", members: [ { _id:  0, host:  "1.1.1.1:27017" }, { _id:  1, host:  "2.2.2.2:27017" } ] });
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "replSetInitiate quorum check failed because not all proposed set members responded affirmatively: 2.2.2.2:27017 failed with not running with --replSet",
        "code" : 74,
        "codeName" : "NodeNotFound"
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to start Monog directly with `mongod`, you should always use `systemctl start mongod` for consistency reason. Or use `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` When you are more familiar with MongoDB, then you may use `mongod` with customized options. Did you follow this one: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

Answer (score 0):

When you start MongoDB service with `mongod` (and without `dbpath` option) then default dbPath `/data/db` is used.

However, when you start MongoDB service with `systemctl start mongod` then it reads the config file `/etc/mongod.conf` and in this config file the `dbPath` is set to `/var/lib/mongodb` (or similar)

You must use the same dbPath!

Comment: my `/etc/mongod.conf` has a `dbPath: /var/lib/mongo`.  So I decided to run this command `mongod --auth --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --replSet "rs0" --bind_ip localhost,2.2.2.2` from the server `1.1.1.1`.  But this still yielded the same error output as what I showed in my question.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Perhaps something is mixed up, delete `/var/lib/mongo` and try from scratch.

Comment: I updated my question with some new findings under the section **EXTRA 2020-11-16 0900**.  Essentially using the flag `--bind_ip 0.0.0.0` let me get pass the terminal error.  But still having trouble with the `rs.initiate()` function

Comment: Oh!!! I got it...I'll post a complete answer in a bit.  But basically I needed to do 2 more things after my last update. I need to run `mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --replSet "rs0" --bind_ip 0.0.0.0` on both the servers with terminal window opened for each.  Notice that I dropped the `--auth` flag and I use `--bind_ip 0.0.0.0` .

Answer (score -1):

check cd /tmp folder inside , there must be a socket file, check the permission. and try to connect that secondary outside of the VM.